# Replace same values in Python dictionary with None

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I would like to replace every value in the dictionary, which has a 'not_recorded' value with None value.

Dict:

```
 data = {'Date' : ['3-Mar', '20-Mar', '20-Apr', '21-Apr', '29-Apr', '7-May', '30-May', '31-May', '7-Jun', '16-Jun',
 '1-Jul', '2-Jul', '10-Jul'],
        'Site_1' : [0.5840, 0.8159, 0.7789, 0.7665, 0.8510, 0.7428, 'not_recorded', 0.6820, 0.8714, 0.8902, 'not_recorded', 0.8289, 0.6877],
        'Site_2' : [0.6196, 0.8291, 0.7686, 0.7848, 0.9935, 0.7406, 'not_recorded', 0.6952, 0.6952, 0.6952, 'not_recorded', 0.8119, 'not_recorded']}
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
    def replace_string_with_None(value_to_find, value_for_replacing):
        for value in data.values():
                if value == value_to_find:
                        data[value] = value_for_replacing
replace_string_with_None("not_recorded", None)
print(data)
```

Comment: You can't access a dictionary by its values. Use its keys instead.

Comment: The 'for' loop is setting the 'value' variable to one of the lists, not to the items in the lists. You can check this by replacing the body of the 'for' loop with 'print value'. So you need another inner loop (or preferably a list comprehension) that goes through the list doing the substitutions. Also you should really be passing in the data as a parameter to the function.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog This is not true, you absolutely can access the values in a dictionary in this way. That's what the .values() method is for.

Comment: @SimonHibbs ok then perhaps I should rephrase - it doesn't make sense to access the dictionary **by** its values (even though that might work if some of the values were equal to keys by coincidence)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog If you know you want to go through all of the values, regardless of what they keys are, then going via the keys is needless overhead.

Comment: @SimonHibbs I'm not sure what point you're trying to make – OP also has to **update** the values which is not possible without using their corresponding keys. Anyway, I simply meant that writing `data[value]` when `value` is part of `data.values()` does not make sense.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Ok fair enough, I think I misunderstood you. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
data = {'Date' : ['3-Mar', '20-Mar', '20-Apr', '21-Apr', '29-Apr', '7-May', '30-May', '31-May', '7-Jun', '16-Jun',
 '1-Jul', '2-Jul', '10-Jul'],
        'Site_1' : [0.5840, 0.8159, 0.7789, 0.7665, 0.8510, 0.7428, 'not_recorded', 0.6820, 0.8714, 0.8902, 'not_recorded', 0.8289, 0.6877],
        'Site_2' : [0.6196, 0.8291, 0.7686, 0.7848, 0.9935, 0.7406, 'not_recorded', 0.6952, 0.6952, 0.6952, 'not_recorded', 0.8119, 'not_recorded']}

def replace_string_with_None(data, value_to_find, value_for_replacing):
    for key, value in data.items():
        data[key] = [value_for_replacing if i == value_to_find else i for i in value]
    return data

data = replace_string_with_None(data, "not_recorded", None)
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Date': ['3-Mar',
          '20-Mar',
          '20-Apr',
          '21-Apr',
          '29-Apr',
          '7-May',
          '30-May',
          '31-May',
          '7-Jun',
          '16-Jun',
          '1-Jul',
          '2-Jul',
          '10-Jul'],
 'Site_1': [0.584,
            0.8159,
            0.7789,
            0.7665,
            0.851,
            0.7428,
            None,
            0.682,
            0.8714,
            0.8902,
            None,
            0.8289,
            0.6877],
 'Site_2': [0.6196,
            0.8291,
            0.7686,
            0.7848,
            0.9935,
            0.7406,
            None,
            0.6952,
            0.6952,
            0.6952,
            None,
            0.8119,
            None]}
```

Answer (score 0):

> data.values()

is a list of lists. You need to add another loop in order to iterate the internal list and compare to 'not_recorded'